# How to access variable from a function in a required file that required another file? Can I do it directly, without using $GLOBALS?

Tags: php, variables, scope, global, require

So I have the following 3 files:

index.php

```
<?php
    require("require/functions.php");
    $g = getGroup();
    var_dump($data);
    die();
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
    function getGroup(){
        if(condition) $g = 1;
        else if(another condition) $g = 2;
        else if...etc
        require("data/$g.php");
        return $g;
    }
?>
```

An example e.g. data/1.php file:

```
<?php
    $data = ["Some random data"];
?>
```

I tried various approaches like using `global $data` in `index.php` and various other things, but didn't have any luck using this approach

I could do it by changing the `getGroup()` function to `getGroupAndData()` and returning `[$g, $data]`, however that isn't really ideal...

Likewise I also created a global variable `$temp` in `functions.php`, used `$temp = $data`, then could use `global $temp` in the `index.php` file

My current preferred method is just to use `$GLOBALS['data'] = $data` inside the `getGroup()`, function, though I'm curious, is there anyway I can access this `$data` array from within the `index.php` file without having to use these workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: Just declare `global $data` at the top of your function (inside it)

Comment: That will get it to work, however it seems to be a roundabout way of doing it. The approach you said that was not ideal (`getGroupAndData`) looks to be a far better and more readable approach that is consistent across varying scopes

Comment: This is a crazy approach. Stop it right away.